# Android - Wrong image present in ImageView at run time

Tags: android, imageview, src

I have an `ImageView` and I set its `src` property to show an image from my res/drawable images.
I can see the image change in the designer, **but** when I run it I can see the old icon appear(and always the same one).

I've tried to clean/Rebuild, Invalidate caches/reset, delete the R file manually, none of that is helping.

What can I do more ?

Comment: Sounds like you're deleting it from one drawable folder and leaving it in the rest.

Comment: The png file is located at \app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\image.png.
Do I need to delete it from any other place ?

Comment: It could be at `\app\src\main\res\drawable-ldpi\image.png`, `\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\image.png`, `\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\image.png`, etc, or even `\app\src\main\res\drawable\image.png`.

Comment: that is wher the file is ... \app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\.
As I wrote.

Comment: What I meant was for you to make sure the file does not exist in any of the other folders, not just the `drawable-hdpi` one.

Answer (score -1):

your image file must be in the res directory not in the src directory.
put your image in this directory : yourappdirectory/res/drawable-hdpi

good luck